# Angular library Cannot find module 'name-lib'

Tags: angular

I created library on my workspace, follow all angular procedure with ng g library etcc....
Build library ng build name-lib --prod, after i have a lib on my dist folder.

i add the path on tsconfig.json

```
"paths": {
  "name-lib": ["dist/name-lib"],
  "name-lib/*": ["dist/name-lib/*"]
}
```

Now whe i try to use: import { LoginLibModule } from 'name-lib';

Error:
Cannot find module 'name-lib' or its corresponding type declarations.

does anyone have any good solutions?

Thanks